# Does state get updated after shouldComponentUpdate and before render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new to React, just a question on how component's state object get updated. After analyzing some code, I think:

In update phase, state get updated after shouldComponentUpdate method but before render method, is my understanding correct?

If the answer is yes, is it another dedicated method(sth like "UpdatingState") to updated the state object?

Comment: As you can see from lifecycle diagram: http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/ you are right.

Answer (score 1):

updating state in react is done through the `setState` lifecycle method

you can call it like this `this.setState({name: 'new name'})` this updates the state object key `name` to be the new value, in this case `new name`

updating objects is a little bit harder. you have to first clone the object. then change the value then reset the state like so

```
state = {
   person: {
     name: 'peter',
     age: 25
}

const copy = {...this.state.person}
copy.name = 'new name'
this.setState({copy})
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the state will be updated (`setState`) after shouldComponentUpdate. The order of update phase would be

1. getDerivedStateFromProps
2. shouldComponentUpdate
3. render
4. componentDidUpdate

to update state use `setState`

Comment: I know I need to use `setState`, but when does `setState` actually get invoked? after shouldComponentUpdate  and before render?

Comment: yes, `setState` will be executed after shouldComponentUpdate.

Comment: and before render?

Comment: Yes before render

Answer (score 0):

there is a function that is called after each update in state and props:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps , prevState)
```